# Print just first output line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a code which extracts certain text from a specified url, but it gives me 2 or 3(depending on the webpage) subsequent same output in different lines. I just need to use the first output. How should I do that?
This is my code:-

```
 import requests, re
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 url="http://www.barneys.com/raf-simons-%22boys%22-poplin-shirt-504182589.html#start=2"
 r=requests.get(url)
 soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
 links=soup.find_all("a")
 g_d4=soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
 for item in g_d4:
      links_2=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/'))
      pattern_2=re.compile("clothing/(\w+)")
      for link in links_2:
          match_1=pattern_2.search(link["href"])
          if match_1:
             print (match_1.group(1))
```

My output is:

```
         shirts
         shirts
         shirts
```

I want my output to be like just:

```
         shirts
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which of the answers you need so Ill answer both.

#### unique results

If you want unique results from across the page, you can use sets to do something like:

```
for item in g_d4:
    links_2=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/'))
    pattern_2=re.compile("clothing/(\w+)")
    matches = set()
    for link in links_2:
        match_1=pattern_2.search(link["href"])
        if match_1:
            matches.add(match_1.group(1))
    print(matches)
```

#### single result

If you want just the first result in each iteration, you can break within the inner loop:

```
for item in g_d4:
    links_2=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/'))
    pattern_2=re.compile("clothing/(\w+)")
    for link in links_2:
        match_1=pattern_2.search(link["href"])
        if match_1:
            print(match_1.group(1))
            break
```

Comment: yep, thats what I wanted. Thanks!